# Is it possible to add your own derivable traits, or are these fixed by the compiler?

Tags: rust

The `derive` attribute allows certain traits to be automatically implemented for data structures. The reference gives the example:

```
#[derive(PartialEq, Clone)]
struct Foo<T> {
   a: i32,
   b: T
}
```

Is it possible to add your own derivable traits, or are these fixed by the compiler?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A small number of derivable traits are [hard-coded in the compiler](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.56.0/compiler/rustc_builtin_macros/src/lib.rs#L100-L112).

Rust 1.15 stabilized [procedural macros](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch19-06-macros.html) which allow for the creation of custom `derive` attributes. If you need to support stable versions of Rust before 1.15, there is a [crate](https://crates.io/crates/custom_derive) that uses macro hackery to derive custom traits.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have an example of the crate macros?

Comment: @andygavin No, sorry, I haven't actually used it yet. But [the docs](https://danielkeep.github.io/rust-custom-derive/doc/custom_derive/index.html) have an example.

Answer (score 10):

The release of Rust 1.15 allows custom traits to be derived. They easiest way to do this is by using the [syn](https://github.com/dtolnay/syn) and [quote](https://github.com/dtolnay/quote) crates.