# How to write a custom derive macro?

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I'm trying to write my own derive mode macro in Rust, and the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/procedural-macros.html#derive-mode-macros) on it is somewhat lacking in examples.

I have a struct like:

```
#[derive(MyMacroHere)]
struct Example {
    id: i64,
    value: Option<String>,
}
```

I want my macro to generate a method à la

```
fn set_fields(&mut self, id: i64, value: Option<String>) {
    // ...
}
```

What are the basic steps to use the `TokenStream` trait to achieve something like that?

Comment: The reference probably isn't the best place to go for documentation on procedural macros - have you read [the 'Macros' appendix from the Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/appendix-04-macros.html#procedural-macros-for-custom-derive) and the API docs for the [`proc_macro`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/proc_macro/index.html) built-in library? They'd be the best places to start, in my opinion.

Comment: The general gist of how procedural macros work is that they take in a `TokenStream` (in this case, it'd be the tokens that make up the definition of `Example`), and then run a piece of code that generates a new `TokenStream` to add to the program (this would be the tokens that make up the `set_fields` definition). People generally use the `syn` crate to translate the input tokens to a proper Rust syntax tree, and the `quote` crate to generate the output.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

1. Create a crate for your procedural macros:

   ```
   cargo new my_derive --lib
   ```
2. Edit the Cargo.toml to make it a procedural macro crate:

   ```ini
   [lib]
   proc-macro = true
   ```
3. Implement your procedural macro:

   ```rust
   extern crate proc_macro;

   use proc_macro::TokenStream;

   #[proc_macro_derive(MyMacroHere)]
   pub fn my_macro_here_derive(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream { 
       // ...
   }
   ```
4. Import the procedural macro and use it:

   ```rust
   extern crate my_derive;

   use my_derive::MyMacroHere;

   #[derive(MyMacroHere)]
   struct Example {
       id: i64,
       value: Option<String>,
   }
   ```

---

The hard part is in implementation of the macro. Most people use the [syn](https://crates.io/crates/syn) and [quote](https://crates.io/crates/quote) crates to parse the incoming Rust code and then generate new code.

For example, syn's documentation starts with [an example of a custom derive](https://docs.rs/syn/0.15.18/syn/#example-of-a-custom-derive). You will parse the struct (or enum or union) and then handle the various ways of defining a struct (unit, tuple, named fields). You'll collect the information you need (type, maybe name), then you'll generate the appropriate code.

See also:

- [How to Write a Custom `derive` Macro](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-06-macros.html#how-to-write-a-custom-derive-macro)
- [Documentation for `proc_macro`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/proc_macro/)
- [Documentation for `syn`](https://docs.rs/syn/)
- [Documentation for `quote`](https://docs.rs/quote/)
- [Is it possible to add your own derivable traits, or are these fixed by the compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32626316/155423)

Comment: To make parsing easier, I've built [darling](https://crates.io/crates/darling). It exposes a `serde`-like API where you define a struct for the arguments your macro needs, and then pass it a `syn::DeriveInput`. It handles parsing, field validation, duplicate field checking, and error creation.