# Idiomatic way of getting dynamic state in struct

Tags: rust

I have a struct like this:

```rust
struct TeddyBear {
    mood: Option<Box<dyn Mood>>,
}
```

"Mood" is a `trait`. Now there are two possible moods: "Happy" and "Sleepy", `struct`s that implement the `trait`. I've drafted a playground example [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=23998dbadd841a029f4005c258d01d99).

I'm trying to learn the best way to get the current mood of the teddy-bear at different times in the program.

What I did was to return string values particular to each mood, but it feels somewhat hackish. An `enum` of values would likely work too, but I would have to remember to add to it each time a new Mood is added. I would like to know if there's a way to use "Happy" or "Sleepy" directly.

Thank you!

Comment: you would not have to remember with an enum, if you use `match` with an exhaustive pattern (all cases without a `_`) the compiler will remind you to cover those cases too. Which, imo, is best.

Answer (score 0):

You could have an enum:

```
enum MoodKind {
    Happy,
    Sleepy,
}
```

And a method:

```
trait Mood {
    fn mood_kind() -> MoodKind;
}
```

> but I would have to remember to add to it each time a new Mood is added.

To avoid implementing this the right way each time, a custom derive attribute has to be used. Rust has no builtin runtime reflection. Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53135923/how-to-write-a-custom-derive-macro) as a pointer.

It is not trivial, so think twice about that. Maybe the number of moods is not too big, and you can maintain them manually?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm curious what is the idiomatic approach in Rust for checking the "mood". Using strings was the approach I took, but I'm not particularly happy with it, nor do I believe it's the best approach.

Comment: As a side-note, I'm not sure how I would use this in my example. Do you mean to say I should add the `#[derive(Debug)]` to my Happy and Sleepy `struct`s, and remove the `get_mood` method from the trait? How would I get the mood in `main` then?

Comment: Yes, if you add #derive to each of your moods, a new method is generated for each of them. In this case that method would return some debug description, and it is possible to get it using `format!("{:?}", mood)`. What do you mean "check the mood"? Do you want methods like `is_happy()`, `is_sleepy()`, or maybe `mood_kind()` returning an enum? Could you update your question to clarify that?

Comment: I've updated the answer from using strings to using an enum.